# Django tastypie error json field

Tags: python, django, tastypie

how are you.

I have a problem with Django Tastypie since I am returning a single field called description but I would like this field when I do a get to return an object to me.

I attach the image of how I currently have it since I am consuming the api with a front and it arrives to me as a string.

Thank you [image: Imagen]

Comment: you need to provide code for how you are creating response json.

Comment: Read about `DictField`